# Is it correct to use multiple Attribute Sets in one Category while uploading products? Magento 2

Tags: magento2.3, category, attribute-set, upload

My Question is about **Product Uploading**!

Is it the right practice to use multiple 'Attribute Sets' in the same category for uploading products?

> Why I am asking this is, we have more than thirty thousand products.
> On the category page, I see some product attributes repeatedly. For example,
> "HEIGHT" is repeating two times.
>
> When I explore those products inside both "HEIGHT"s, I saw different
> attribute sets have been used under the same Category.
>
> If it is not a correct way to use different attribute sets in one
> category, than in our case is there a programmatic solution possible
> to this issue or we have to edit all those products?